# no se porque da este error

Tags: visual-studio

nodemon : El término 'nodemon' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.
Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo
de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- nodemon server.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Prueba escribiendo ese mismo comando en CMD

Comment: visual studio o visual studio code?